# How to document the type of a global variable with JSDOC

Tags: javascript, global-variables, jsdoc

I have a piece of code that runs on the browser. There's a library loaded from a CDN that puts some variables on the global scope. How can I document the type of that variable?

For example

index.hmtl => puts `globalVariable` on the global scope

```
...
<script src="//cdn.library.com/library.js"></script>
...
```

index.js => uses `globalVariable`

```
/**
 * @type {SomeType} globalVariable
 */
const foo = globalVariable()
```

Something like that so I can specify the type of `globalVariable`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typecasting and the `window` global can be your friend here.

To cast:

```
const globalVariable = /** @type {someType} */ (window.globalVariable);
```

To modify the `window` global add an externs file that contains:

```
/** @type {someType} */
window.prototype.globalVariable = function() {};
```

Comment: Awesome! It works! Just a minor detail, can you add "@type" before "{someType}" in the first code snippet? It may be also worth mentioning that it breaks [no-use-before-define](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define) and it can be bypassed adding `// eslint-disable-line` at the end of the line. Thanks!

Comment: It seems `const foo = (foo)` results in `foo` being undefined. Had to do `const globalVariable = /** @type {someType} */ (window.globalVariable)`, so maybe the linting error was quite on point

Comment: Added `@type`, sorry about that. WRT the lint: I did wonder if that would be the case, but I figured that was a separate issue that was probably solvable by anyone asking this question... So good work, my faith in humanity is partially restored (no small feat).